# using graphic to draw pentagon

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

Currently i'm trying to draw a pentagon with graphic but to no avil as i'm unable to get the points. So far I had tried it to draw out a triangle which I had succeeded , code is as below;

```
          SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(painting);
            PointF point1 = new PointF(25, 350);
            PointF point2 = new PointF(450, 350);
            PointF point3 = new PointF(225, 50);
            PointF[] curvePoints = { point1, point2, point3 };
            g.FillPolygon(sb, curvePoints);
            paintstart = false;
```

(using triangle value as base)i thought of adding two more points (since pentagon have 5 sides) and my code for pentagon goes like this

```
           SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(painting);
            PointF point1 = new PointF(25, 350);
            PointF point2 = new PointF(450, 350);
            PointF point3 = new PointF(225, 50);
            PointF point4 = new PointF(10, 150);
            PointF point5 = new Point(475, 150); 
            PointF[] curvePoints = { point1, point2, point3, point4,point5};
            g.FillPolygon(sb, curvePoints);
            paintstart = false;
```

after added the 5th point, the whole shape figure goes distorted while 4th point remain alright.
Any idea why after adding the 5th point, the whole shape goes distorted? I add + 15 value to the x value of the pentagon base(450)and y axis remained the same.
Any help is appreciated thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the points matters when you have more than three points:

```
PointF[] curvePoints = { point1, point2, point5, point3, point4 };
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks! Now it looked like a pentagon, didn't know that the order matters. Appreciated your answer !